# Yii2 get those record whose fields are not empty

Tags: php, yii2

I would like to return onlyb those records whose field called issue is not empty

Please note that issue field is a text type field\

This is what ive tried

```
    public static function getIssueTrucks(){

 return static::find()->where(['truck_status' => 10])
    ->andWhere(['not', ['issue' => null]])  //here the issue field  
        ->orderBy(['updated_at' => SORT_DESC])->all();

}
```

The above returns all the records whose statis is 10 and even when the field issue is empty

Where am i going wrong

Comment: you are storing empty or null in database ?

Comment: am storing empty not null  that is when a json is finally returned it has  " "

Comment: you get `NOT (issue IS NULL)`

Comment: `->andWhere(['<>', 'issue', ''])`